# Getting started with particle system in 2d

Tags: 2d, particles

I would like to get started with particle systems in 2d.  But I really don't know where to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest you read up on gamedevelopment. Also in which language are you going to develop it in? I suggest you start by searching for frameworks and such. For example for c# there is XNA from MS and if you use java you can use open GL read up about those things first and then search for some tutorials I guess there are a lot to find

Comment: Language is c++, but I'm not really looking into anything language specific.  More about the theory and good design.